# Calculating multi year 5-day running percentile

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, percentile

I need to calculate 3-day running 90th percentile value for each calendar day from multi-year data. I have 30-year daily datasets looking like this,

```
            year    month   day  value
DATE                    
01/01/1980  1980    1       1    12.3957
02/01/1980  1980    1       2    8.2678
03/01/1980  1980    1       3    11.9438
04/01/1980  1980    1       4    8.8035
05/01/1980  1980    1       5    2.749
...             ... ... ...
27/01/2010  2010    1       27   4.1186
28/01/2010  2010    1       28   5.9619
29/01/2010  2010    1       29   8.8146
30/01/2010  2010    1       30   12.9397
31/01/2010  2010    1       31   11.8427
```

In order to calculate the 90th percentile value on Jan 1st, I have to choose a 3-day window centered on Jan 1st for 30 years. So, I would have 90 (3*30) data points for each day. I can compute the percentile and record this as the 90th percentile value for that center day. Then, I would repeat this process for each day by moving the 3-day window until I have a new dataframe filled with percentile values for each day from Jan 1st to Dec 31st.

The problem is, my datasets are sometimes a normal calendar year(i.e. 365/366 days), sometimes only have 365 days, or 360 days(12 months*30 days). I am dropping the leap days but I do not know which dataset is which.

I tried to iterate over days but I have a problem when there is no Feb 29 or Jan 31. I tried slicing with multiple conditions with a for loop but I had the same problem.

I could not figure out how I can choose a 3-day moving window for 30 years and compute the percentile.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem. First, I dropped Feb 29. Therefore, I would have either a 365-day or 360-day dataset. Then, I changed the datetime index to string.

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%m-%d')
```

I used enumerate on the unique index values to loop through all days. I used the if-else block to be able to choose a 5-day window centered on the first and last 2 days of a year, otherwise `start` would be greater than `end`.

For Jan 1st, it would be

```
current = '01-01'
start = '12-30'
end = '01-03'
```

So, I used `or |` and `and &` operators together for choosing the dates.

```
90p = {}
for count, date in enumerate(df.index.unique()):
    start = df.index[count-2]
    end = df.index[count+2]
    current = df.index[count]
    print("My date is %s, 2 day before is %s and 2 day later is %s" % (current, start, end))

    # day[0]
    if count == 0:
        temp = df.loc[((df.index >= current) & (df.index <= end)) | ((df.index >= df.index[count - 2]) & (df.index <= df.index[count - 1]))]
        90p[date] = temp.value.quantile(0.9)
    
    # day[1]
    elif count == 1:
        temp = df.loc[((df.index >= df.index[count - 1]) & (df.index <= end)) | ((df.index >= df.index[count - 2]) & (df.index <= df.index[count - 2]))]
        90p[date] = temp.value.quantile(0.9)
    
    # day[-2]
    elif count == len(df.index.unique()) - 2:
        temp = df.loc[((df.index >= df.index[count - 2]) & (df.index <= df.index[count + 1])) | ((df.index >= df.index[count + 2]) & (df.index <= df.index[count + 2]))]
        90p[date] = temp.value.quantile(0.9)

    # day[-1]
    elif count == len(df.index.unique()) - 1:
        temp = df.loc[((df.index >= df.index[count - 2]) & (df.index <= df.index[count])) | ((df.index >= df.index[count + 1]) & (df.index <= df.index[count + 2]))]
        90p[date] = temp.value.quantile(0.9)
    
    # day[2:-2]
    else:
        temp = df.loc[(df.index >= start) & (df.index <= end)]  
        90p[date] = temp.value.quantile(0.9)
```